# How do I use Redis to communicate between my API and the socket server (Angular2/Laravel)

Tags: laravel, websocket, angular

I'm using:
- Laravel as my backend
- Angular 2 as my frontend

I'm trying to show all connected users to my website real time information using Laravel,Angular 2 and Redis.

I installed redis for windows: https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads

Played with it a little:

[image]

But I have no idea where to go from here, couldn't find any instructions or help about using redis with angular2/laravel, and I hope you can help me.

My first goal is simple: Update a variable for all connected users in my app.

For example:
- user clicks a button
- another user who connected to the website can see "Someone clicked this button!" without refreshing the page

How I can make it with the current technology I use (Angular2/Laravel)? (If there is something else than a redis, it's fine)